# Indexed views in SQL Server 2014 object explorer without index node

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2014

In the SQL Server 2014 Management Studio's object explorer indexed views with schemabinding don't have an index node. Thus, you can create and drop Indexes for views only via T-SQL. The SQL Server Management Studio 2012 still shows the index node.

Has anybody experienced the same or is there some Management Studio setting in version 12.0.2000.8 which I am missing?

Many thanks in advance.

Marcus

Answer (score 4):

This has been fixed in Cumulative Update 5, check here and download from Microsoft site: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3014193

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug according only the combination of SSMS 2014 and SQL Server 2014.
The bug has been adressed by MS und will be fixed in future Releases.

See here: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/920968/indexed-views-in-sql-server-2014-object-explorer-without-index-node

Answer (score 0):

as jens mentioned it's a known bug.

A currently working work-around is to use ssms 2012 to manipulate those indexes until 2014 is bug-fuxed. (you just won't be able to create 2014 features such as memory optimized tables using ssms 2012)